# How to load other websites using server side php (Laravel) like Hypothes.is or ProjectHuddle?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, iframe

I'm wondering how one might accomplish something like https://hypothes.is/, or https://projecthuddle.io/
so that a user can supply their own URL, and the server loads external website using server side PHP, and embed some iframe layer on top of it to add annotations.

When you load external URL, it goes to a url like https://via.hypothes.is/https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl, and loads the actual site instead of putting it in iframe, and inserts iframe to the page to annotate it.

My approach at first was to just use an iframe, but the problem was I cannot insert my own annotations and etc into the actual website.

I am using Laravel 5.4 and PHP. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: file_get_contents(), curl. just grab the whole page rewrite urls\images and other paths if you need to.

Comment: Yeah, I also thought about that. Thanks for the response. I agree it is good idea, just unsure how all the relative links and non-absolute urls can be handled, especially when the user can browse to other urls within the page.

Comment: since you can see pages like: https://via.hypothes.is/https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https://www.google.ca/%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl#identifier ive reported them as  a deceptive site

Comment: lol... what..? Okay, but this wordpress plugin for annotation does similar thing though. https://projecthuddle.io/ I don't think it is uncommon for loading different website instead of using an iframe nowadays. I agree it shouldn't be able to load login pages.

Comment: they dont even follow the robots text file they are immoral at best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your initial question:

```
$pageContent = file_get_contents($url);
```

works quite well.

Regarding changing the links, I'd start by an xpath query, and adjusting the href's to be absolute, against your own URL. Maybe something like:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query("a[starts-with(@href, '/')") as $a){

}
```

and I'll leave it up to you to modify and reprint the DOM.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one